# Solving the Kepler problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics

I'm trying to solve the Kepler problem using the Lagrangian,

$$L = \frac{1}{2} m (\dot{r}^2 + r^2 \dot{\phi}^2) - U(r) $$

which after quite a bit of fiddling with, by noting that the angular momentum $M = mr^2 \dot{\phi}$ is a constant of motion and also $M = 2m\dot{f}$ where $\dot{f}$ s the sectorial velocity, leads to

$$\phi = \int{\frac{M dr/r^2}{\sqrt{2m(E - U(r)) - M^2 / r^2}}}{}$$

Now for the Kepler problem $U(r) \propto 1 / r$ and so $U(r) = \alpha / r$. Plugging that in, we get,

$$\phi = \int{\frac{M}{r^2\sqrt{2m(E + \alpha / r) - M^2  /r^2}}}{dr}$$

However, plugging that integration into [WolphramAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5B%28M%20%2F%20r%5E2%29%20%2F%20%28%282%20m%20%28E%20%2B%20alpha%2Fr%29%20-%20M%5E2%20%2F%20r%5E2%29%5E%281%2F2%29%29%2C%20r%5D%20WolframAlpha) gives an imaginary solution.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You may not be doing anything wrong. You may be looking at something like $\arcsin$ in disguise: recall that (on the appropriate branch) $\arcsin z=-\,i\,\log\left(i\,z+\sqrt{1-z^2}\right)$. Does that help?

Comment: *What am I doing wrong?* The answer is you are using Mathematica to do your homework for you. It's a great tool, but you have to take its answers with a grain of salt.

Comment: @DavidHammen I wouldn't say that using Mathematica to evaluate an integral is _doing it wrong_. But I do agree that one should be ready to get the result in an unexpected form and have to adapt it to expectations.

Comment: Additionally to Rod's comment, note that you are evaluating an _indefinite_ integral. It's nothing wrong with it being imaginary, because it's defined up to an additive constant, which can be complex.

Comment: @Ruslan - I didn't say that WA is doing it wrong. It does however do things stupidly. While it knows that $\int_0^x e^t\,dt = e^x - 1$, it somehow thinks that the best representation of $\int_0^x e^{-t}\,dt$ is $\sinh (x) - \cosh(x) + 1$. That is correct, but it's mindless and it's stupid. What's wrong with $1-e^{-x}$?

Comment: @DavidHammen yeah, you didn't say _WA_ is doing it wrong, you said it's OP who did wrong when tried to use WA to evaluate the integral. I doubt the homework in physics here is the process of integration. As for WA, Mathematica/WA doesn't try to simplify when you tell it to integrate, that's why by its tricky internal algorithms you get different representations of seemingly similar things. Ask it to simplify — and chances are you'll get it as you want.

Comment: @Ruslan This is (or at least it was) a fairly standard homework problem for sophomore or junior physics majors taking the standard classical mechanics class, and it is just a matter of grinding through an integral.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use
$$
\frac{d}{dr} \cos^{-1} \left(f\left(r\right)\right) = -\left[1-\left(f\left(r\right)\right)^2\right]^{-1/2} \frac{df}{dr}
$$
with
$$
f\left(r\right) = \frac{M/r - m \alpha/M}{\sqrt{2 m E + m^2 \alpha^2 / M^2}}
$$
to show that
$$
\int dr \frac{M / r^2}{\sqrt{2 m E + 2 m \alpha / r - M^2 / r^2}} = \cos^{-1} \left(\frac{M/r - m \alpha/M}{\sqrt{2 m E + m^2 \alpha^2 / M^2}}\right) + C
$$